# Add hint to function after declaring

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the screenshot of `$.each()` hint:

[image: hint]

I'm using Visual Studio, is there a way to add hint to a function after declaring?

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    Each: function () {

    }
});
```

I wanna add some text to `Each()` function to explain how to use this function.

Is it possible? And how?

Comment: I know of this type of documentation as "Javadoc" although that's specific to Java (I am unaware of the general term for this sort of documentation).  I know that in C# you can use three / marks to indicate documentation, eg `///<summary>This function does a thing</summary>` but I do not know if that will work for Javascript.

Comment: @Draco18s You can follow MikeC's answer with the link inside

Comment: That looks precisely like the Javadoc syntax.  Cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSDoc comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162307.aspx).

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    /**
     * @description Enter your description here
     * @param {type} arg  Use this for arguments
     * @param {type} arg2 Multiple if using multiple args
     * @return {type} Return type
     */
    Each: function(arg, arg2) {
    }
});
```